# Getting a Vector to JList (Java)

Tags: java, user-interface, vector, jlist

I am having trouble with accessing a vector from a different class and displaying into a Jlist.

So for example, (this is one class)

```
 // I have a vector that contains an object in one class

 private Vector<Person> personList;

 public MakePerson(Vector personList){
 this.personList = personList;

 // I have some GUI formatting here and button action listeners which 
 add a person when a button is pressed.
 }
```

Action Listner

```
 public void action(Actionevent event){
 Person people = new Person();

 // The information from the GUI is grabbed and placed into a variable.

 people.setName(name);
 people.setAge(age);
 people.setheight(tall);
 personList.add(people);
 }

 // To my knowledge this is adding the object to the vector, please let me
 know if otherwise any help is greatly appreciated
```

Now here is where I am having trouble (this is a different class in the same package)

```
 public class ChoosePerson extends Jpanel {

 private Vector<Person> personList;
 private Jlist myList;

 public ChoosePerson(Vector personList){

 this.person = personList;
 myList = new JList(personList);

 //This is part of my panel where the Vector should be displayed but doesn't

 Jpanel list = new Jpanel();
 JScrollPane myPane = new JScrollPane(myList);
 list.add(myPane);

//This is where I am having trouble
 }
```

The purpose of the code is to add a person from the first class GUI and display it on the second class GUI using the vectors. (Note: The MakePerson and ChoosePerson GUI are seperated by tabs)

Comment: Are you sure you are initializing the vector `personList` somewhere?

Comment: To my knowledge when the information is entered in the GUI Applet, the code is extracting information from the text boxes and creating an object person from it. I have revised the code and it is creating a vector list in the MakePerson class and displaying it correctly through a JTextArea. I can't, however, display the same information in the ChoosePerson class using JList. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is that you have to [create](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating) a [`ListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) which wraps the [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) and then you configure the [`JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) to use this model. Then you [create a `Renderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) to display the objects (`Person`) in your list as needed.

I suggest you go through the full example from the [official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).